# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'then'

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I was checking alot of exist questions wiht similar error but cannot find anwer which can help me with my error
I have select with cases

```
select 
    case 
    when e.EthnCode in ('N','A','B','P','W') then ethnicity
    else 'Multi' 
    end as Ethnicity,
    case when cat.CategCode IN ('CH','IN','NB','PG','PP','SR')then Category else 0 end as ' ',
 --COUNT (c.EthnCode) as '(A) tottal Numbers of participamts by Rase', 
 sum(case when C.StatusID =1 or C.StatusID =2 then 1 else 0 end),
 sum(case when c.Hispanic then 1 else 0 end) as 'Hisp'
from  Ethnicity E
LEFT JOIN Clients C
ON c.EthnCode = e.EthnCode 
LEFT join Category cat 
ON c.CategCode = cat.CategCode
where c.StatusID = 1 
group by case 
    when e.EthnCode in ('N','A','B','P','W') then ethnicity
    else 'Balance Reporting More Than One Race' 
    end
```

and it throws error

```
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'then'.
```

Line 9

```
 sum(case when c.Hispanic then 1 else 0 end) as 'Hisp'
```

it is underlining Hispanic
Please need help :)

Comment: What type is c.Hispanic?  The expression `case when c.Hispanic` should be `case when c.Hispanic = [something]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 sum(case when c.Hispanic then 1 else 0 end) as 'Hisp'
```

Change as (please use the correct value and data type in the comparison)

```
 sum(case when c.Hispanic = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'Hisp'
```

Or to a simple case as

```
 sum(case c.Hispanic when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'Hisp'
```

Comment: it throwing a new error Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'Ethnicity.Ethnicity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.it trowing new error

Comment: Well your old error is sorted, that is a new one. You need to correct group by clause for the aggregate functions.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't think C.Hispanic is a boolean.
`Case When C.Hispanic = 1 Then` ....

or some such will sort it out.